# Are ssh installs removed on git push in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

I have a running scalable Openshift application. I have installed some softwares via ssh. Now I am a bit worried about these softwares getting removed when I git push the next time.

So if this case, can I depend on `action hooks` for doing this installation task.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your software will get removed when you push or when the app scales.

I had the same problem when I needed to add GraphicsMagick to my Node install.

What I did was:

- Added the source code to my local repository
- Pushed it to openshift
- Compiled the software and added it to app-root/repo/node_modules/.bin
- Added this gist: https://gist.github.com/ryanj/9751652
- Used SCP to download the gist and the compiled binary to my local machine
- Added the two files to the repository
- Deleted the source code out of the repository
- Ran "git update-index --chmod=+x FILENAME" to make the executable execute.
- Committed and pushed the code

Big thanks to ryanj and OpenShift for helping me with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the files you ssh'ed into your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR then they won't get deleted.